# Declare global variable that can be used on other function

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, variables, globals, timthumb

I have AJAX image upload function where I can get `attachment_id` value.
I want to save that as global variable and use it in different function that sets post thumbnail when it's exist.

This is what I have so far and NOT working.

**Image upload**

```
function write_here_featured_image_upload() {
    //var_dump($_FILES);

    // Temporary post id
    $post_id = 0;

    // These files need to be included as dependencies when on the front end.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

    // Let WordPress handle the upload.
    global $attachment_id;
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file' , $post_id );
    $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' );

    echo $image_attributes[0];

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_write_here_img_upload', 'write_here_featured_image_upload' );
```

**Add post function**

```
function write_here_add_new_post() {
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
    //echo "Post Added ".$post_id;

    if(isset($attachment_id)){
        set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attachment_id );
    }
}
```

`global $attachment_id` does not seem to be working. what is the proper way to do this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. When does the AJAX request run? You realize that an AJAX request is an independent request to the server and `globals` won't populate across requests?

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I want to upload an image with AJAX and get `attachment_id` then use that `attachment_id` when the entire form is submitted to set the post thumbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account your comments to your question, what you should do is:

- Your AJAX function should return the attachment ID to the client
- The frontend script should catch that response and store the attachment ID somewhere, or just populate a hidden input field in your form
- When you submit the entire form - add the attachment ID to the POST. If you have populated a hidden input field - the attachment ID will be automatically added to POST.

Don't forget to do some security checks when submitting the form - is the current user an author of the post with 'attachment ID' ID?

Comment: Yes I figured I can set hidden field value to `attachment_id` which I can use to submit a form. I'm not sure about the security check tho. I'm send `wp_nonce_field( 'new-post', 'new-post-nonce' )` on form submit and check that on the function. Will this be good enough?